# Filtering when adding elements by id

Tags: ruby

Tell me how to do this, where you can read about it, because I do not understand at all how to implement it. Thanks.

```
def initialize
  @arr = []
end

def items(init)
  arrfinish = init - @arr
  @arr = (@arr + init).uniq
  yield arrfinish
end

def idefine(find_text)

end
```

The class has a method(items) that connects arrays by removing duplicate elements. I need to make sure that the idefine
method receives the key by which filtering will be performed when adding new elements, I will give an example below.

```
app_handler.idefine('id')
app_handler.items([{'id' => 1}, {'id' => 1, 'test_key' => 'Some data'}, {'id' => 2}])
```

From this example, the second element with id = 1 should be ignored.

Comment: Does `'test_key' => 'Some data'` is also removed ?

Comment: Yes, the entire object is deleted.

Comment: Do you actually want `items` to `yield` anything, and if so what?  (You're not passing a block in your example code, and if you're only yielding once then you might as well just use a return value instead.)  Also, is it safe to assume that `idefine` will *not* be called after any items have been added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, putting aside the class definition, what I understand of the question is:

*In an array of hashes, remove the hashes that contain a duplicate value of a given key.*

The following function filter the hashes and copy the content of the selected ones in a new array:

```rb
require 'set'

def no_dup_val key, arr
  previous_values = Set[]
  arr.each_with_object([]) do |hash,result|
    next unless hash.has_key?(key)
    next if previous_values.include?(hash[key])
    previous_values << hash[key]
    result << hash.dup
  end
end
```

Which gives you:

```rb
no_dup_val 'id', [{'id' => 1}, {'id' => 1, 'key' => 'data'}, {'id' => 2}, {'stock' => 3}, {'e-stock'=>0}]
#=> [{"id"=>1}, {"id"=>2}]
```

Note that the hashes that don't contain the key are also removed, that's **my** choice, which leads to the following questions:

- What happens when the key is not present in a hash?
- What happens when the `item` function is called more than once? Do you take into account the hashes already in `@arr`?
- What happens when you call `idefine` with a new key? Do you filter the existing elements of `@arr` with the new key?

As you can see, you need to be a little more specific about what you want to do.

---

**Update**

If you don't care about copying the contents of the hashes then these  may fit your needs.

1. Hashes without the `id` key are removed:

```rb
def no_dup_val key, arr
  arr.filter{ |h| h.has_key?(key) }.uniq{ |h| h[key] }
end

no_dup_val 'id', [{'id' => 1}, {'id' => 1, 'key' => 'data'}, {'id' => 2}, {'stock' => 3}, {'e-stock'=>0}]
#=> [{"id"=>1}, {"id"=>2}]
```

2. Hashes without the `id` key are treated as having `"id" => nil` (so the first will be kept):

```rb
def no_dup_val key, arr
  arr.uniq{ |h| h[key] }
end

no_dup_val 'id', [{'id' => 1}, {'id' => 1, 'key' => 'data'}, {'id' => 2}, {'stock' => 3}, {'e-stock'=>0}]
#=> [{"id"=>1}, {"id"=>2}, {"stock"=>3}]
```

3. All the hashes without the `id` key are kept: